# 6-month vs 2-year visit visa

Tags: visas

I am a British citizen who lives in the UK. I’ve applied for a 6-month visit visa for my husband who lives in Germany as a refugee with a 3-year resident permit. If he gets the 6-month, visa would it be better to apply for a 2-year visa or another 6-month? Which one is likely to get accepted? What are the requirements for the 2-year visa?

My husband is getting benefits from the job centre, as he can’t work because he can't speak German.

Answer (score 1):

Chances of acceptance for either of those are based on his circumstances and you are thinking too far ahead: get the first visa acceptance, comply with the terms, and only then think about which visa to apply for next. You should also consider a spouse visa (I'm surprised you haven't mentioned this) and the 'Surinder Singh route' which would entail you living with him outside the UK for a while before you could both enter the UK under European treaty rights.

Comment: The only issue I have with the spouse visa is I am a part time student and work part time and so I do not earn 18,600. I’ve asked about the surinder singh rout and what the problem is that he is on the job centre and either of us have to work and provide money for the two of us. That’s the only issue we have at the moment.

Comment: Don't assume not speaking German is an absolute barrier to employment in Germany (see linked article) but I agree the other options don't seem to be available for you. https://www.thelocal.de/20171025/why-some-foreigners-live-in-germany-without-mastering-the-language

Comment: He tried to get a job all wanted basic german skills which he has not yet got